# Java Windows Touch click release too quick

Tags: java, windows, swing, touch, mouseevent

I have a Swing application in Windows 7 that has a button which shows a depressed state when the mouse is held down on it which works great however when I use a touch screen when I press and hold on it the mouse event registers a pressed and released state one after the other quickly (the fact I'm still holding on it is being ignored). Any ideas please? I'd like to have it hold down the button while the finger is still on it.

```
    boolean showDepressedState = false;

    JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        showDepressedState = (e.getID() == 1);           
    });
```

Comment: It may help to see your current code.

Comment: code added. With a mouse the showDepressd state is switch to true when the mouse is held down on the button and then false when it released however with Window 7 touch screen its switched to true then false straight away even though I still have my finger on it.